# Merge statement in Execute SQL Task failing

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, merge

I am building this in Visual Studio SSIS - I have two tables each with three fields each. One table is a temp table that I load with daily values, the other is the production table. I want to take the daily temp table and if as record exists in the prod table by the "Key" I want to update the summary values by adding the values already in the prod table to the values coming from the temp table. Below is the code I thought would work but I am getting an error of "Error: 0xC002F210 at Create-Update EMS Summary Table, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "MERGE EMSComplianceTrnSummary as target
USING EMSE..." failed with the following error: "The insert column list used in the MERGE statement cannot contain multi-part identifiers."

Any help to make this work?

SQL Code:

```
MERGE EMSComplianceSummary as target
USING EMSComplianceSummaryTemp as source ON (target.key = source.key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET target.sumtoon = target.sumtoon + source.sumtoon,
             target.summoving = target.summoving + source.summoving
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (target.trainkey, target.sumtoon, target.summoving)
  VALUES (source.trainkey, source.sumtoon, source.summoving)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement identifies what the target table is `EMSComplianceSummary` which is then aliased as target. Therefore, it's not needed or allowed in the INSERT portion of your MERGE statement

```
MERGE EMSComplianceSummary as target
USING EMSComplianceSummaryTemp as source ON (target.key = source.key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET target.sumtoon = target.sumtoon + source.sumtoon,
             target.summoving = target.summoving + source.summoving
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (trainkey, sumtoon, summoving)
  VALUES (source.trainkey, source.sumtoon, source.summoving);
```

I also added a semicolon as a statement terminator because it is required.

> The MERGE statement requires a semicolon (;) as a statement
>   terminator. Error 10713 is raised when a MERGE statement is run
>   without the terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to remove "target." from each of the columns in your insert list.  It already knows you are inserting to the target.

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon at the beginning and also at the of the Merge statement. I know, the comma at the beginning is not mandatory (like the ;with CTE statement) but has helped me in the past.